# Querying large results while preserving the order

Tags: google-bigquery

I need to query a rather substantial number of rows (around 4,000,000) from a log table so that I can save them into a CSV file.
My query looks like this:

```
SELECT
  time_unixtime
  field1,
  field2,
  field3
FROM
  dataset.execute_log20151118
WHERE
  field9 = 'unique_id'
ORDER BY
  time_unixtime
```

When I run it using the SDK, I encounter a `Resources exceeded during query execution` error, which makes sense since the data is likely to exceed the [128 MB compressed limit](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quota-policy#queries).
Enabling the `allowLargeResults` flag in the job configuration seems to be the natural solution, but this would forbid the query to order the results. Of course, I can still run the query without the `ORDER BY` and then sort the results locally, but this doesn't look like a good solution.
Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: Why do you need the rows sorted? Frequently we find that BigQuery users who want to sort large amounts of data can accomplish their goal in a different way.

Comment: This is a requirement from the clients who will be using the CSV file. The rows don't necessarily need to be ordered when I query them, but they must already be sorted inside the CSV file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only idea I have, is to break this query into multiple ones by putting filter on time_unixtime field - each time limitig query to subset of data that can fit into ORDER BY. Then you will end up with several CSV files, each one is ordered by time_unixtime, and they can be concatenated into single sorted file.

Comment: Thank you for your response, this solution is definitely more efficient and faster to implement.  
I'm worried about the fact that the query is going to process the whole table each time though, which means that if I were to run it for each hour of the day, the costs would be multiplied by 24.
Then again, I can make groups larger and smarter (group together periods of time with little data) than this.
I can't think of anything better, but please let me wait a little to see if anyone has another idea before I accept this as the answer.

Comment: @Jean-LoupRoussel-Clouet Mosha is a BQ engineer, and part of the team that builds BQ.

Comment: I'm going to shard the data into smaller tables soon, hopefully this will solve the size issue. Anyway, this is the solution I'm using for the moment and it's working just fine. Thank you again for your help!